# Add Class for <LI> on prev and next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

How to add class for list li tag simultaneously when click on next and prev button.

on click of next and prev the active class should add and remove simultaneously for li.

Can anybody solve this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();

  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    $(".list li").addClass("active");
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $(".divs div:visible").hide();
      $(".divs div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {

    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $(".divs div:visible").hide();
      $(".divs div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
  <div class="cls4">4</div>
  <div class="cls5">5</div>
  <div class="cls6">6</div>
  <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: want to add/remove active class for list li on click of next and prev.

Comment: @rockeydsouza check below fiddler for answer. let me know if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/7bs1L98f/)

What you are suppose to do is, you are suppose to add same class names for the corresponding `li`. On `next()` or `previous()` click, get the visible div's class and make use of it to set active on the `list li`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i change $ to jquery will it work because my whole code is in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The `active` class will apply to `<li>` tags if you press the next button now. And if you want that the `perv` button do the same should change your code into this:

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
   $(".list li").addClass("active");
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

If I got your mean correctly, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following methods:

`.next().addClass('your-class')` and `.prev().addClass('your-class')`

Hope it may help you....